# I can’t send email from my own mail server using cyberpanel webmail

Tags: vps, cyber-panel, vultr, rainloop

I have been trying to create my own server using cyberpanel on vultr I already created my email and issue ssl and configured my dns and my reverse dns but when I login to my rainloop my message would be sent but won’t deliver but if I send a mail to my rainloop mail account I get it quickly but can’t reply from my rainloop,I have tried setting up my imap and pop3 in the rainloop admin to connect it with gmail still the same way please what should I do

Answer (score 1):

1. There are three SSL options on CyberPanel, you need to select email SSL for your email to work
2. Every provider blocks port 25 to control spam. Contact your ISP or if you are hosting your server on Digital Ocean or AWS request them to unblock port 25 ( They never agree, at least for me )